# Fetch token and post a webservice

Tags: c#, .net, rest, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a webservice written in Net Weaver gateway. I need to `POST` a data for which first I have to fetch an `x-csrf-token`. I am getting that token by a `GET` method. Upto there my code is working fine. But when I have to send the data using `POST` with the fetched `x-csrf-token` I am getting `InvalidOperation` exception or 403 bad request.

I want to remind you that the webservice is working fine in the RestClient of firefox, so there is no issue with webservice request. Also I want to pass the token as a header field in the `POST` call. So fetching token is a must. Token is dynamically generated and cannot be hardcoded.

I can share code if anyone needs to see it. Code is for WINDOWS mobile 6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.Added header Cookie  and its working fine.

Comment: how you did this can you some some example ?

Comment: i fetch value from "Set-Cookie" header of response and passed this values as "Cookie" header of next request.